# If -else if- else statement not working as expected

Tags: arrays, c, function, if-statement, caesar-cipher

I am using 'Apple Clang' on MacOSX.

The below code is a shift cipher that uses one of 8 different shift values depending on the position of the char in a string (which is the message).

Going by the rules it should encode '`ABC` ' (with the int array d set to `d = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`) and output  `3c 45 45 -6f` but is instead printing `44 45 46 -6f`... which leads me to hypothesize that the if-else_if-else statements are not doing what they should.

[-6f is a termination marker, not dependent on d[] or message].

The below is my attempt at a  minimum, reproducible example.

I have only included the shortened `encrypt()` function, the main function calling `encrypt()` as well as the other functions which check, respectively, if the position number `i` of the `char` in `msg[]` is a part of the Catalan, Fibonacci , Lucas, Pentagonal, Hexagonal, or Prime number series, and if none, whether it is odd or even. (for context on what these are, look [here](https://edublognss.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/famous-mathematical-sequences-and-series/))

```
#include <stdio>
#include <string.h>
int ctln(int);
int fib(int);
int luc(int);
int pent(int);
int hex(int);
int prm(int);


void encrypt(){
    int d[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    
    char msg[3002]; int en[3001];
    printf("\nType Message - \n\n"); 
    fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin); // stores message in msg
    int len = strlen(msg); // gets length of string , needs string.h
    if(msg[len-1] == '\n')
         msg[len-1] = '\0'; // to remove \n added by fgets()
    len -- ; // len reduced to position of char before '\0

    char ch; int j;
    for(int i =0;i < len ;i++ ) // for loop en
    {   ch = msg[i];

        if(ctln(i)==1)
            j = ch + d[2];
        else if(fib(i)==1)
            j = ch - d[4];
        else if(luc(i)==1)
            j = ch + d[0];
        else if(pent(i)==1)
            j = ch - d[6];
        else if(hex(i)==1)
            j = ch + d[3];
        else if(prm(i)==1)
            j = ch - d[7];
        else {
            if(i%2 == 0)
                j = ch + d[1];
            else
                j = ch - d[5];
        }
        en[i] = j;
    }
    
    printf("\nEncoded message -\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i < len; i++) // prints hex till last actual char, blocks garbage vals
    {
        printf("%x ", en[i]); // prints shifted char val in hex w.r.t. ASCII 
    }
    printf("-6f\n"); // -6f = -111, used to terminate input in decrypt()
}

int main()
{
    encrypt();
    return 0;
}
int ctln(int x)
{
    int arr[]= {1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430};int con=0;
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        if(arr[i] == x)
            con = 1;
    }
    return con;
}

int fib(int x)
{
    int arr[]= {0, 3, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584};
    int con=0;
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        if(arr[i] == x)
            con = 1;
    }
    return con;
}

int luc(int x)
{
    int arr[]= {4, 7, 11, 16, 17, 19, 31, 37, 41, 47, 53, 61, 71, 79, 113, 313, 353, 503, 613, 617, 863, 1097, 1361};
    int con=0;
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        if(arr[i] == x)
            con = 1;
            break;
    }
    return con;
}

int pent(int x)
{
    int arr[]= {12, 22, 35, 51, 70, 92, 117, 145, 176, 210, 247, 287, 330, 376, 425, 477, 532, 590, 651, 715, 782, 852, 925, 1001, 1080, 1162, 1247, 1335, 1426, 1520, 1617, 1717, 1820, 1926, 2035, 2147, 2262, 2380, 2501, 2625, 2752, 2882};
    int con=0;
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        if(arr[i] == x)
            con = 1;
            break;
    }
    return con;
}

int hex(int x)
{
    int arr[]= {0, 1, 6, 15, 28, 45, 66, 91, 120, 153, 190, 231, 276, 325, 378, 435, 496, 561, 630, 703, 780, 861, 946, 1035, 1128, 1225, 1326, 1431, 1540, 1653, 1770, 1891, 2016, 2145, 2278, 2415, 2556, 2701, 2850};
    int con=0;
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        if(arr[i] == x)
            con = 1;
            break;
    }
    return con;
}

int prm(int x)
{
    int arr[]= {7,13,23,29,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627,1637,1657,1663,1667,1669,1693,1697,1699,1709,1721,1723,1733,1741,1747,1753,1759,1777,1783,1787,1789,1801,1811,1823,1831,1847,1861,1867,1871,1873,1877,1879,1889,1901,1907,1913,1931,1933,1949,1951,1973,1979,1987,1993,1997,1999,2003,2011,2017,2027,2029,2039,2053,2063,2069,2081,2083,2087,2089,2099,2111,2113,2129,2131,2137,2141,2143,2153,2161,2179,2203,2207,2213,2221,2237,2239,2243,2251,2267,2269,2273,2281,2287,2293,2297,2309,2311,2333,2339,2341,2347,2351,2357,2371,2377,2381,2383,2389,2393,2399,2411,2417,2423,2437,2441,2447,2459,2467,2473,2477,2503,2521,2531,2539,2543,2549,2551,2557,2579,2591,2593,2609,2617,2621,2633,2647,2657,2659,2663,2671,2677,2683,2687,2689,2693,2699,2707,2711,2713,2719,2729,2731,2741,2749,2753,2767,2777,2789,2791,2797,2801,2803,2819,2833,2837,2843,2851,2857,2861,2879,2887,2897,2903,2909,2917,2927,2939,2953,2957,2963,2969,2971,2999,3001};
    int con=0;
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        if(arr[i] == x)
            con = 1;
            break;
    }
    return con;
}
```

There are no compiler errors/warnings in the main code, which is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psLji6Z2RIcpAMcgCuwxQaoMvE1uZzND/view?usp=sharing) .

Comment: prm() is broken.  It breaks on the first iteration, match or not.

Comment: `i < sizeof(arr)` is wrong because sizeof counts _bytes_, not ints. Use `i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`

Comment: @MartinJames oh.. how so ?

Comment: All those array search functions are broken for the same reason.

Comment: @MartinJames how , where have I screwed up ?

Comment: The break is outside the scope of the if.  It is executed on the first iteration.

Comment: `len--` should only be executed if `msg[len-1] == '\n'`

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to use a ***debugger***. Using a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement, and step into your function calls, while monitoring variables and their values. If you do that then it should become very obvious what the problem is.

Comment: I also recommend that you use an editor focus on programming, which usually have auto-indentation and can reformat code to "fix" indentation. If you use such a function it should also become obvious what the problem with your check functions are.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ if you cannot debug, you cannot program:(

Comment: @MartinJamesThanks, I realised my folly !

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yep fixed both of those as well , thanks a ton !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude absolutely, I will ahead and learn debugging

Comment: @user13863346 'I will ahead and learn debugging'  yay!  Result!  :)

Comment: @MartinJames yeah its a pain to go to stack overflow every time ;) also ... ' I will **go** ahead and learn debugging.

Comment: @MartinJames new problems are occurring, now in `decrypt()` :( Can you help here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317914/while-loops-and-arrays-causing-very-odd-behaviour-maybe-a-memory-mixup-c-lan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Martinjames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james) for pointing out that my `break;` was outside the scope of the if statement, which is fixed simply by using parentheses.

Thanks to [@PaulOgilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie) for pointing out that

1. "`i < sizeof(arr)` is wrong because sizeof counts bytes, not ints. Use `i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` ".
2. " `len--` should only be executed if `msg[len-1] == '\n'` "

Lastly, Thanks to [@Someprogrammerdude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) for pointing me towards learning debugging, very helpful for future panic.