# While loops and arrays causing very odd behaviour...maybe a memory mixup

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, pointers, memory

I'm tired of this tom-foolery occurring during runtime , although I'm sure we all are, when our programs screw up at runtime in the most obscure ways.

Getting to the point, the entire source code is a bit large to place here, but still <200 lines, so that's [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psLji6Z2RIcpAMcgCuwxQaoMvE1uZzND/view?usp=sharing) . Use it if running the program, since the code I *will* post below is just functions, where I think the error lies.

Context : This is a sort of shift cipher with 8 different shifts taken using an 8 digit pin.

The issue is strange. Basically, the `encrypt()` function works correctly always -I've matched it by doing the algorithm for myself on paper ; for example, ABC is correctly encoded to `3c 45 46 -6f` when the Pin is `12345678`.

The strange issues are with the `decrypt()` function.

When the program is run for the first time, trying to run `decrypt()` on a **valid** ciphertext-pin pair **always** returns nothing except a `/n` (newline) .  When tried with a **different valid pin-ciphertext pair**, after a successful run of `encrypt()` is done first, the `decrypt()` function just returns either the same message which was just encrypted or some other random output from the previously encoded message.

Without further ado, the legendarily screwed up decrypt function which I have rebuilt **thrice** now -

```
void decrypt()
{
    printf("\n");
    int *digits = pin(); int d[8];
    getchar();
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        d[i] = *(digits + i); //puts each digit in a local array.

    printf("\nEnter encoded message -\n\n");
    getchar();
    
    int j; char ch, msg[3002];
    for(int i=0; i < 3000;i++)
    {
        scanf("%x",&j);

        if(j==-111){
            msg[i] = '\0'; //terminates string with \0
            break; 
        }
        else{
            if(ctln(i)==1)
                ch = j - d[2];
            else if(fib(i)==1)
                ch = j + d[4];
            else if(luc(i)==1)
                ch = j - d[0];
            else if(pent(i)==1)
                ch = j + d[6];
            else if(hex(i)==1)
                ch = j - d[3];
            else if(prm(i)==1)
                ch = j + d[7];
            else {
                if(i%2 == 0)
                    ch = j - d[1];
                else
                    ch = j + d[5];          
            msg[i] = ch;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nDecrypted message -\n\n");
    puts(msg);    
}
```

For context, as well as finding the culprits here, do make sure to read the full code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psLji6Z2RIcpAMcgCuwxQaoMvE1uZzND/view?usp=sharing) , with the `pin()` returning a pointer to a `static int array` holding all 8 digits , as well as the `ctln()` , `fib()`, `luc()`, `pent()`, `hex()`, `prm()` [ which check if position value `i` of `char` in message is a part of Catalan, Fibonacci , Lucas, Pentagon, Hexagon, Prime number series. More [here](https://edublognss.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/famous-mathematical-sequences-and-series/).

**Edit 1**

I have already tried keeping different variable names, and some other things I can't fully recall. Also, because it is very relevant, below is the `pin()` function:

```
int *pin() 
{
    
    int num,q=0; static int pins[8];

    
    printf("Enter 8-digit PIN : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    
    for(register int i = 10000000 ; i >= 1 ; i = (i/10)) // i is position of digit.
    {
        int d = ((num - (num % i)) / i); // d stores 'digit' ( divides quotient of (num % i) by i) 
        pins[q] = d; q++;
        num = (num - ( d * i )); 
    }
    

    return pins ; // pointer to static array storing digits of PIN 
}
```

**Edit 2**

I had wrongly assigned `pins[6]` rather than `pins[8]` in the original code, I have corrected it but am still facing the same errors.

**Edit 3**

After correcting the mistake pointed out by MikeCAT, it now ignores the first character when deciphering.

**Edit 4**

The `getchar()` before `scanf()` was to blame, removing it fixes the last issue too. Thanks @MikeCAT !

Comment: Storing 8-digit pin to `static int pins[6];` invokes *undefined behavior* for out-of-bounds write.

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry, I have changed that to `pins[8]` but still the same errors

Comment: To be very clear, I don't know advanced C enough to know **for sure** if this is a memory issue. I'm only **guessing**.

Comment: You don't need to add "(C language)" to your question titles. We can see the C language in the list of question tags.

Comment: @Blastfurnace noted .

Comment: What purpose do the two calls to `getchar()` have?

Comment: @derpirscher where is the second one ? And I only use getchars() to contain unnecessary newlines produced inexplicably

Comment: I see one after the call to `pin()` and a second one after `printf("enter ecoded message")` Especially the second one might be a problem because it might swallow the first character of the message you type ( but I may be wrong, my c is a bit rusty)

Comment: @derpirscher you were on spot. Now the issue is how to printf the \n\n without it skipping taking my input or having to use a getchar()

Comment: I don't think `getchar` has any effect on `stdout`. I understand the first `getchar` after reading the pin, as `scanf` does not consume trailing whitespaces, but I honestly don't get what you expect from a `getchar` after `printf("... \n\n")`. If you don't want newlines on the screen, don't output them.

Comment: The posted code, when run through a C compiler, with warnings enabled, results in a LONG list of warnings, about `type mismatch` in call to `scanf()`.  Function: `strlen()` returns a type: `size_t`, not a `int`.  There are LOTS of comparisons between `signed` and `unsigned` values which will fail if the `signed` value is < 0.  There are LOTS of comparisons between `int` and `char` will can fail.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `for(register int i = 10000000 ; i >= 1 ; i = (i/10))`  in modern C, the modifier: `register` means nothing suggest removing that modifier

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (edx == 'e' || edx == 'E')` and `else if (edx == 'd' || edx == 'D')` and `else if (edx == 'x' || edx == 'X')`  Strongly suggest: `#include <ctype.h>`  Then using the function: `toupper()` or `tolower()` so only have to make one comparison. for each of the 3 allowed inputs

Comment: regarding this menu: `printf("\n-------------------\n\nEncode(e) / Decode(d) : ");`  This fails to inform the user of the third valid input: `x`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &num);`  Should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:  `if( scanf("%d", &num) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for key value failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like: `int i = 10000000;`  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` or `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use the meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `pins[q] = d; q++;` for ease of understanding and readability (by us humans, the compiler doesn't care) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin);`  What if the call to `fgets()` fails?  The posted code fails to check for that condition

Comment: regarding: `msg[len-1] = '\0'; // to remove \n added by fgets()`  This is not reliable.  Suggest: `msg[ strcspn( msg, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding; `size_t len = strlen(msg); // gets length of string , needs string.h
 
 if(msg[len-1] == '\n')
 {
    msg[len-1] = '\0'; // to remove \n added by fgets()
        len -- ; // len reduced to position of char before '\0'
    }`  what if all the user entered was a <ctrl-z> (EOF)?  What if all the user entered was a `'\n'`?  suggest checking the `len` is greater than 0 before messing with the last char of the message

Comment: regarding; `{   ch = msg[i];`  Please put separate statements on separate lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `decrypt()` function, `msg[i] = ch;` is executed only if none of the functions `ctln, fib, luc, pent, hex, prm` returned `1`.

Therefore, uninitialized value of non-static local variable `msg`, which is indeterminate, may be used for printing and *undefined behavior* may be invoked.

The part

```
            msg[i] = ch;
            }
```

should be

```
            }
            msg[i] = ch;
```

as it is done in `encrypt()` function.

Comment: Mike ! Another discrepancy ...when I give it `12345678` as key and `3c 45 46 -6f` as ciphertext, I prints `BC` instead of `ABC` which it should....

Comment: It may be because `3` is consumed by `getchar();` after `printf("\nEnter encoded message -\n\n");` and `c` is used as the first element.

Comment: Mike, your right, and figured much the same just now... but does this imply that it's impossible for me to use two \n\n in my print() ? Because if I do that without the getchar(), it skips taking my input

Comment: @user13863346, are you running your program inside an IDE? Because if the `getchar()` calls have any seeming interaction with your output, then that suggests a buffering issue of a kind that is relatively common inside IDEs, but very unusual for (the same) programs running directly in a terminal window.

Comment: No because I don't think output will usually affect reading. `%x` will skip whitespace characters, so I don't think any `getchar()` in `decrypt()` are required. What input is skipped? Try `" %c"` instead of `"%c"` in `main()` to have it skip whitespace characters.